# combine recursive and move options in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using recursive=true option in File Component route.
I want to use the move option in order to move the file to sufolder of the current folder , and also rename the file by adding a "backup_" prefix.
I notice that the recursive make a problem as it create directories structure for the move file and also add the prefix to the directories name.
How can I solve it and combine recursive and move options ?

Comment: You can configure almost all you want to do in the move option where you can use the file language to control the name. See more at: http://camel.apache.org/file-language

Comment: yes thank you , but it seems that the recursive option conflicts it as it effects the rename

Comment: Just do something like `move=subfolder/backup-${file:onlyname}`

Comment: yes but I want it to be under my current directory from which I do the reading , so I did : move=${file:parent}subfolder/backup-${file:onlyname} and this couse infinit loop

Comment: Okay sounds like you need to set a filter to skip all backup-* files. Because Camel will see it as a new file.

Comment: yes that solve it thank you